# Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1c-1ubuntu4) on Ubuntu 19.10 [Dependency Error]

Tags: openssh, libssl

I am trying to install `libssl-dev` on **ubuntu 19.10** But i am getting dependency error as

```
Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1c-1ubuntu4)
```

I was trying to upgrade OpenSSH on Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: This is the duplicate question. Please refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251468/e-package-libssl1-1-has-no-installation-candidate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install using the debian file from [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+build/17865247)
`libssl-dev_1.1.1d-1+ubuntu19.04.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb`

downloaded and installed the **libssl** debian package manually.