# Unable to install mongodb in ubuntu 22.04 (mongodb-org, libssl1.1)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-22.04

### On following installation instructions from MongoDB official site.

- While installing **mongodb-org** package getting the following error

```
sudo apt install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

- I tried installing **libssl1.1** package using apt but I was unable to do so it throws following error.

```
E: Package 'libssl1.1' has no installation candidate
```

please someone help.

Comment: This is the duplicate question. Please refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251468/e-package-libssl1-1-has-no-installation-candidate)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

###### It seems mongodb require specific version of libssl1.1

- you can download debian file of that version and install using following commands. Most probably it will resolve this issue.

```
sudo wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: thanks  it save my day on ubunto  for install mongodb

Answer (score 2):

After hours of looking for a solution I was satisfied with, I finally stumbled across one! Hope this helps anyone else looking to install MongoDB community edition without sacrificing security by using libssl1.1 (the solution here uses >3.0.

MongoDB has the repository for Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) hidden away. It definitely still isn't on the documentation installation pages as of the time I am posting this. Check it out yourself: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/jammy/mongodb-org/

The following code will add the repository and install the latest mongodb-org on your system:

```
sudo apt-get install wget gpg
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.mongodb.gpg
sudo install -D -o root -g root -m 644 packages.mongodb.gpg /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mongodb.gpg
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mongodb.gpg] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
rm -f packages.mongodb.gpg
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```