# Unable to locate package libssl1.1

Tags: package, airflow, system

I'm trying to Setting up Apache Airflow Cluster on linux,Install System Level Requirements [flowing URL (part 1.1)](https://skwrites.in/setting-up-apache-airflow-cluster/), with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends freetds-bin krb5-user ldap-utils libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libssl1.1 locales lsb-release sasl2-bin sqlite3 unixodbc
```

I get the following output:

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libssl1.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libssl1.1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libssl1.1'
```

how can i fix it?

p/s:i using airflow version 2.3.3
and Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 is using libssl3 . that document you are following probably is based on older ubuntu version

Comment: This is the duplicate question. Please refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251468/e-package-libssl1-1-has-no-installation-candidate)

Comment: This is the duplicate question. Please refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251468/e-package-libssl1-1-has-no-installation-candidate)